# validation error while committing code on git

Tags: angular, git-commit, lint-staged

I was working on angular java project. and while committing code i found below error.

---

× Validation Error:

> Invalid value for 'linters': { '*.@(js)': [ 'eslint --fix', 'git add' ], '*.@(ts)': [ 'tslint --fix', 'git add' ] }

Advanced configuration has been deprecated.

× Validation Error:

> Invalid value for 'ignore': [ 'spec-dtslint/**/*.{js,ts}', 'api_guard/**/*.{js,ts}' ]

Advanced configuration has been deprecated.

---

I reinstalled npm with command- `npm install`, `yarn install`, `yarn build:libs` (required steps for my project setup) then I was able to see the changes on git bash like unstaged and staged changes. However it was returning same error again and again.
tried one solution from stackoverflow - remove `.git/hooks` and reinstall npm - `npm install`.
still not worked for me.

Comment: i managed to resolve this issue by removing unnecessary folders like extra node_module (node_module1 ) and dist (dist1) from folder structure and checked on git status i saw the commit already submitted.

Comment: Your node_modules and dist folders should be in your .gitignore file, they shouldn't be committed to your repo